# AXS Tokens disappeared

Tags: tokens

a couple of days ago, I tried to used the axs token on uniswap and suddenly they disappeared from metamask and my account balance says 0 on etherscan?? I can still see the transaction on etherscan where i bought them 125 day ago en no transaction of them leaving my account?? please advise on what might have happened I have 518.959843162754895838 tokens .. are they stolen and if so... how did that happen? please help!!

transaction of the buy

https://etherscan.io/tx/0xe266613cec6454c3108cf4265f0d9ea1df020fbf1aaee44a806eff77103ca322

token balance

https://etherscan.io/token/0xf5d669627376ebd411e34b98f19c868c8aba5ada?a=0x9dbbc8873fab0b3533a3f432799a19ae656c3af5#tokenAnalytics

Answer (score 0):

Either you - or someone else in control of your account - swapped them on Uniswap for API3 token 4 days later (29th December 2020).

Here's the transaction:

https://etherscan.io/tx/0x6a047c37cc90312ea50aab6759828fc1268ec0d4cd5ebfa819706b3e2fcc3ce5